# combining data from two columns

Tags: excel

I'm working with two separate excel spreadsheets. One has user names and their manager and the other spreadsheet has the updated list of users.

I need to move over the list of manger's to the second spreadsheet but the problem is that the second sheet has nearly 200 more entries, so I can't do a normal sort.

How can I match up these two sheets?

Comment: In the second spreadsheet, can you do a VLOOKUP?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a vlookup. if you google 'vlookup' or look on youtube you should be able to find answers.